# Event handler triggered multiple times in close succession on doc lib causing issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, development, document-library, event-receivers

I'm using an `ItemUpdating` event with a Document Library to run a Task generation procedure. After stepping through, it's causing issues when I check out the document which I'm forced to do after adding versioning.

There are Two calls that come almost at the same time repeating every statement/conditional so when I check out the document I run into issues.

Is there a way to delay the event handler from triggering so that one call is made while the others are queued? Or is there a way to delay the second call of an event handler within the code?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 3):

Before modifying item, you should Disable event firing

```
this.DisableEventFiring();
```

After finish updating you can Enable it using

```
this.EnableEventFiring();
```

**Identify if event is fired as part of Check-in**

```
if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null && properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] != null)
{
    //This is when the update event is triggered by check-in.
}
else
{
    //This is triggered by events other than check-in action.
}
```

**Review if event receiver is registered multiple times**

1. Create a console application and review event receivers

   ```
   using (SPSite sps = new SPSite(SiteName))
   {
       using (SPWeb spw = sps.OpenWeb())
       {
           SPList splist = spw.Lists[ListName];
           foreach (SPEventReceiverDefinition sprd in splist.EventReceivers)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(sprd.Class + " " + sprd.Name);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: when using disableeventfiring() it states that the method is obsolete, use eventfiringenabled.

Comment: Yes you can use `this.EventFiringEnabled = false;` and then `this.EventFiringEnabled = true;`.